# Embedded web page not working on iis server

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio, iis

In my webpage, I am doing something like this,

```
<object type="text/html"
    data="/media/examples/webpage"
    width="250"
    height="200">
</object>
```

It works ok in Visual Studio but when deployed on an iis server the page is not loaded and I don't know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what's wrong, I had the change the X-Frame-Options on my IIS server

[Allow others to iframe my site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28294714/allow-others-to-iframe-my-site)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a suffix to the webpage.

If I use `data="/media/examples/webpage"` , it cannot loaded.

[image]

However, it worked after set `data="/media/examples/webpage.html"`.

[image]

Comment: It's an ASP.NET app so there is no suffix or real page

Comment: If it is a classic asp.net app,  page's suffix is ".aspx". If it is a mvc asp.net app, page's suffix is "cshtml".

Comment: It's a .cshtml asp core page that is rendered dynamically

Comment: But it works in VS as localhost:XXXX/pathToDirectoryWhere .cshtml